# Adding an arbitrary edge to a graph in tkz-berge

Tags: tkz-graph, tkz-berge

I would like to be able to add an arbitrary edge to one of the graphs in tkz-berge. For example, in the graph below I want to add an edge between v0 and v4.

[image: cycle graph]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal];
  \grCycle[prefix=v,Math=true,RA=2]{10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The tkz-berge documentation describes many `\Edge...` commands, but they all seem to be schemas for adding edges. I didn't see a command for adding a single, arbitrary edge.

I did try using the plain `\Edge` command from tkz-graph, guessing the automatically generated vertex label, but had no success. For example, I tried the following:

```
\Edge(0)(4);
\Edge($v_0$)($v_4$);
```

I suspect that under the hood there must be a command that's used by the various `\Edge...` commands to add a single edge.

*EDIT* Here's the final solution. The labelling scheme is, for example, vertex v_0 has the label `v0`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal];
  \grCycle[prefix=v,Math=true,RA=2]{10};
  \Edge(v0)(v4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

### OR

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
  \grCycle[prefix=a,Math=true,RA=4]{10}%
  \EdgeInGraphFromOneToComp{a}{10}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### OR

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
    \grCycle[prefix=a,Math=true,RA=4]{10}%
    \Edge[](a0)(a4)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\EdgeInGraphFromOneToComp` command draws edges from a vertex to *all* other vertices in the graph. I just want to draw a single edge.

Comment: from a0 to a4? as above edit

Comment: Grand! Note that in my example, I'm using `Math=true`, so the vertices are labeled with subscripts. However, `\Edge(v0)(v4);` does the trick.

Comment: Glad to be of help--my first time being exposed to `tikz-berge`